# Something like std::bitset in C

Tags: c, bitset

I am looking for opinion on this bitset implementation. It only has 4 functions and they are

set - set a bit/clear - clear a bit/check - test a bit /zero - zero out all bits.

There is another one as well but that isn't meant to be used by the users of bitset.

I have used macro to make the underlying type that bitset uses generic as well as the size. I am very new to macros for generic programming. I have been using them here and there in C++ but it had templates and constexpr so there was never really a need. So I want the emphasis of this review to be on use of macros with a little bit on the actual implementation on the side.

First is some test code that shows how bitset can be used.

```
#include "cim_generic_bitset.h"
#include <stdio.h>
 
enum { n_bits = 150 };
//CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_DECL(state, uint8_t, CIM_BITSET_OF_SIZE(uint8_t, n_bits));
CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_DEF(state, uint8_t, CIM_BITSET_OF_SIZE(uint8_t, n_bits));
 
int main()
{
    uint8_t state[CIM_BITSET_OF_SIZE(uint8_t, n_bits)];
 
    cim_state_bitset_zero(state);
 
    cim_state_bitset_set(state, 0);
    cim_state_bitset_set(state,22);
    cim_state_bitset_set(state, 49);
    cim_state_bitset_set(state, 93);
    cim_state_bitset_set(state, 141);
    cim_state_bitset_set(state, 149);
 
    assert(cim_state_bitset_check(state, 0));
    assert(cim_state_bitset_check(state, 22));
    assert(cim_state_bitset_check(state, 49));
    assert(cim_state_bitset_check(state, 93));
    assert(cim_state_bitset_check(state, 141));
    assert(cim_state_bitset_check(state, 149));
 
    for (int i = 0; i < n_bits; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0 && i != 22 && i != 49 && i != 93 && i != 141 && i != 149)
            assert(!cim_state_bitset_check(state, i));
    }
 
    for (int i = 0; i < n_bits; i++)
        cim_state_bitset_clear(state, i);
 
    assert(!cim_state_bitset_check(state, 0));
    assert(!cim_state_bitset_check(state, 22));
    assert(!cim_state_bitset_check(state, 49));
    assert(!cim_state_bitset_check(state, 93));
    assert(!cim_state_bitset_check(state, 141));
    assert(!cim_state_bitset_check(state, 149));
 
    return 0;
}
```

This is the bitset implementation.

```
#pragma once
 
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
 
typedef struct cim_byte_bit_index
{
    size_t byte;
    size_t bit;
} cim_byte_bit_index;
 
//1 extra sizeof(type) will be allocated if n_bits / sizeof(type) happens to be a whole number 
//but idk how to implement a constexpr ceil soo
#define CIM_BITSET_OF_SIZE(type, n_bits) (size_t)( (n_bits / (sizeof(type) * 8)) + 1)
 
#define CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_ZERO_DECL(name, type, size)\
void cim_##name##_bitset_zero(type* bitfield);
 
#define CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_ZERO_DEF(name, type, size)\
void cim_##name##_bitset_zero(type* bitfield)\
{\
    memset(bitfield, 0, size * sizeof(type));\
}
 
#define CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_GET_BIT_BYTE_INDEX_DECL(name, type, size)\
cim_byte_bit_index cim_get_##name##_byte_bit_index(size_t field_size, size_t index);
 
#define CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_GET_BIT_BYTE_INDEX_DEF(name, type, size)\
cim_byte_bit_index cim_get_##name##_byte_bit_index(size_t field_size, size_t index)\
{\
    size_t word_size = sizeof(type) * 8;\
    size_t which_byte = (size_t)(index / (float)word_size);\
    size_t which_bit = (size_t)(index - (which_byte * word_size));\
    cim_byte_bit_index byte_bit_index;\
    byte_bit_index.byte = which_byte;\
    byte_bit_index.bit = which_bit;\
    return byte_bit_index;\
}
 
#define CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_SET_BIT_DECL(name, type, size)\
void cim_##name##_bitset_set(type* bitfield, size_t index);
 
#define CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_SET_BIT_DEF(name, type, size)\
void cim_##name##_bitset_set(type* bitfield, size_t index)\
{\
    assert(index < size * sizeof(type) * 8 && "Bitset index out of range");\
    cim_byte_bit_index byte_bit_index = cim_get_##name##_byte_bit_index(size, index);\
    bitfield[byte_bit_index.byte] |= 1 << byte_bit_index.bit;\
}
 
 
#define CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_CLEAR_BIT_DECL(name, type, size)\
void cim_##name##_bitset_clear(type* bitfield, size_t index);
 
#define CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_CLEAR_BIT_DEF(name, type, size)\
void cim_##name##_bitset_clear(type* bitfield, size_t index)\
{\
    assert(index < size * sizeof(type) * 8 && "Bitset index out of range");\
    cim_byte_bit_index byte_bit_index = cim_get_##name##_byte_bit_index(size, index);\
    bitfield[byte_bit_index.byte] &= ~(1 << byte_bit_index.bit);\
}
 
 
#define CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_CHECK_BIT_DECL(name, type, size)\
bool cim_##name##_bitset_check(type* bitfield, size_t index);
 
#define CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_CHECK_BIT_DEF(name, type, size)\
bool cim_##name##_bitset_check(type* bitfield, size_t index)\
{\
    assert(index < size * sizeof(type) * 8 && "Bitset index out of range");\
    cim_byte_bit_index byte_bit_index = cim_get_##name##_byte_bit_index(size, index);\
    return bitfield[byte_bit_index.byte] & (1 << byte_bit_index.bit);\
}
 
#define CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_DECL(name, type, size)\
CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_GET_BIT_BYTE_INDEX_DECL(name, type, size)\
CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_SET_BIT_DECL(name, type, size)\
CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_CHECK_BIT_DECL(name, type, size)\
CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_ZERO_DECL(name, type, size)\
CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_CLEAR_BIT_DECL(name, type, size)
 
#define CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_DEF(name, type, size)\
CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_GET_BIT_BYTE_INDEX_DEF(name, type, size)\
CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_SET_BIT_DEF(name, type, size)\
CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_CHECK_BIT_DEF(name, type, size)\
CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_ZERO_DEF(name, type, size)\
CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_CLEAR_BIT_DEF(name, type, size)
```

Comment: Please explain what `size_t which_byte = (size_t)(index / (float)word_size);` is trying to do.  Using _floating point_ with an integer problem is not a good thing.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It is supposed to calculate which byte in the array is the given index in. Index is the bit in the whole array. How about if I convert index to float as well? Is float / float bad as well? Why is it bad? What would be the correct way to divide them?

Comment: sOmEon, Answer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>     size_t word_size = sizeof(type) * 8;\
> ```

That magic number `8` looks like it ought to be `CHAR_BIT`.  The same number crops up in other places where it looks like `CHAR_BIT` is intended.

---

> ```
> //1 extra sizeof(type) will be allocated if n_bits / sizeof(type) happens to be a whole number 
> //but idk how to implement a constexpr ceil soo
> #define CIM_BITSET_OF_SIZE(type, n_bits) (size_t)( (n_bits / (sizeof(type) * 8)) + 1)
> ```

Oops - we need to ensure precedence rules in the expansion, by parenthesising `(n_bits)`.

We should probably avoid the over-allocation by adjusting before we divide:

```
#define CIM_BITSET_OF_SIZE(type, n_bits) \
    ((size_t)((n_bits) - 1) / sizeof (type) / CHAR_BIT) + 1)
```

---

> ```
> #define CIM_GENERIC_BITSET_GET_BIT_BYTE_INDEX_DEF(name, type, size)\
> cim_byte_bit_index cim_get_##name##_byte_bit_index(size_t field_size, size_t index)\
> {\
>     size_t word_size = sizeof(type) * 8;\
> ```

That should probably be a `static const`

---

Instead of having separate `⋯_DECL()` and `⋯_DEF()` macros, perhaps just define functions with file scope (i.e. `static`)?  That will increase opportunities for inlining, too.

Comment: Thank you for the review. My intention with `(size_t)( (n_bits / (sizeof(type) * 8)) + 1)` was for it be be kind of similar to ```ceil((float)n_bits / sizeof(type * 8))```     .   `((size_t)((n_bits) - 1) / sizeof (type) / CHAR_BIT) + 1)` doesn't look quite right. did you mistype something?

Comment: I only inspected that, and haven't unit-tested.  The standard technique for ceiling integer division adds one less than the denominator to the numerator before dividing (i.e. `(p + (q - 1)) / q`.  I refactored that to `((p - 1) + q) / q` ≡ `(p - 1) / q + 1`.  That's all assuming `p ≥ 1`, of course.

Comment: Actually yes that was correct. I just changed the second division in your version to `*` i.e. `((size_t)(((n_bits) - 1)) / (sizeof (type) * 8) + 1)` and it now avoids the extra allocation.

Comment: Yes, `a / (b * c)` is equivalent to `a / b / c` - I was just trying to keep the parens to a minimum.

Comment: Nothing about `assert` being optimized away when the code is not compiled in debug mode? There is at least 1 assert in the macros.

Comment: @pacmaninbw That is intended. I don't want it to be bound checking when not in debug. Is there a reason to?

Answer (score 1):

No need for `float` math.

`float` is simply not needed. Conversions to/from float add unnecessary overhead, implementation defined rounding and loses precision when `word_size` is very large.

```
//size_t which_byte = (size_t)(index / (float)word_size);\
//size_t which_bit = (size_t)(index - (which_byte * word_size));\

size_t which_byte = index / word_size;\
size_t which_bit = index % word_size;\
```

Good compilers see nearby `a/b` and `a%b` and emit efficient code, often calculating both in one step.

Comment: Thanks. So I removed all casts like you mentioned. But for calculating `which_bit` wouldn't `byte_bit_index.bit =  index - byte_bit_index.byte * word_size` be faster than mod? Is there some edge case that it misses or something? All implementations of bitset that I have seen seem to use %. Or would performance just be the same

Comment: @sOmEonE Review answer's "Good compilers see nearby a/b and a%b and emit efficient code, often calculating both in one step.".  After `a/b`, cost of `a%b` is often nil.  With such linear coding "improvements" concerns, code for clarity and let the compiler do its job and you focus on the big issues.  Review [Is premature optimization really the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/94903).

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you

Comment: @sOmEonE IMO, understanding evil and good of premature optimization is a most valuable lesson.  It will save you "Acres of time" (my phrase).